# UISearchController Needs an extra tap to become first responder

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I switched my apps one screen from `UISearchBar` to `UISearchController`. It's a tableview controller. As per design I should not keep the search bar on UI initially unless it is activated, (Normally it's a common practice to keep search bar as the 'tableHeaderView'). The problem was, I have a search button, when tapped 'search bar' should be activated and become first responder.

When tapped on cancel button, it should be removed from UI. However when I'm tapping on the 'Search Bar Button' on navigation bar, the `UISearchController` gets activated, providing a dim background but the keyboard doesn't appear. I need to tap one more time on search bar to bring the keyboard upon UI.

Here's my search bar button action:

```
@IBAction func onTapSearch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    searchController.isActive = true
    searchController.becomeFirstResponder()
    isSearchActive = true
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

I'm configuring the `UISearchController` in my `viewDidLoad` method. Let me know if that part code is any of you want to see, however it's usual code. And I verified I'm not calling anywhere `resignFirstResponder()` method anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this,

**Just replace this line,**

```
searchController.becomeFirstResponder()
```

**With this below,**

```
searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

**Edit,**

```
func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController1: UISearchController) {
    searchController1.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Implement this delegate method and try.

Comment: I had that code first. Was not working, then modified.

Comment: welcome. If you think my answer is helped you than kindly accept it so it will usefull for others.

Comment: yeah it was not allowing me to accept for a minute. :)

Comment: Yeah its ok. :)